# SwiftUI UIPasteboard is cleared when posting to instagram-stories

Tags: ios, swift, uipasteboard, instagram-story

I'm posting an Instagram story from my app and it works perfectly. But when I added a UIPasteboard string value where I store my URL, it's being cleared when I paste it in instagram link. What I notice is Instagram is clearing the paste board items when launched. Is there any way to keep the paste board items in Instagram? Here's my code snippet:

```
let urlScheme = URL(string:"instagram-stories://share")!
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(urlScheme) {

    UIPasteboard.general.string = Global.hostURL // THIS GETS CLEARED
    
    let pasteBoardItems:Array<[String:Any]> = [
        ["com.instagram.sharedSticker.backgroundImage" : background.pngData()!]
    ]
    
    let expirationDate = Date().addingTimeInterval(60 * 5)
    let pasteBoardOptions = [UIPasteboard.OptionsKey.expirationDate: expirationDate]
    UIPasteboard.general.setItems(pasteBoardItems, options: pasteBoardOptions)
    
    UIApplication.shared.open(urlScheme)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UIPasteboard.general.setItems(pasteBoardItems, options: pasteBoardOptions)
UIApplication.shared.open(shareURL, options: [:])
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
    UIPasteboard.general.string = url.absoluteString
   // ☝️.setItems again 0.1s after opening Instagram.
  // or 0.2s, 0.25, 0.3 play around with it until it works.
  // Try to get a value that works 10/10 times. 0.1s wasn't as reliable as 0.2s

}
```

Alternative solution is after
`UIApplication.shared.open(shareURL, options: [:])`

Run `UIPasteboard.general.string = url.absoluteString` in the app delegate's `applicationDidEnterBackground`

Or in SwiftUI's new lifecycle

```
@Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
...
.onChange(of: scenePhase) { scenePhase in
            switch scenePhase {
            case .background:
                    UIPasteboard.general.string = url.absoluteString
                }
```

Comment: tried the latter and it works perfectly! thank you

Comment: This answer is so good! I'm with a flutter app, and managed to achieve my goal with the first method "DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline....."
I used 0.8 as timer
1000% reliable eve with IG closed from the background

Comment: Not working for me. When posting an Instagram reel, I see that the pasteboard is not cleared on the first screen... it's cleared on a subsequent screen in Instagram's flow. I have no way of knowing how long a user will spend on the first screen, and so a timer won't work.